# Swift timer is not executing on precise time

Tags: swift, macos

We have logged event for every 60 second, but a few events are not precise.

Here is event log:-

> seeesion ==== 2019-04-11T14:51:09
>
> seeesion ==== 2019-04-11T14:52:09
>
> seeesion ==== 2019-04-11T14:53:09
>
> **seeesion ==== 2019-04-11T14:54:19**
>
> seeesion ==== 2019-04-11T14:55:09
>
> seeesion ==== 2019-04-11T14:56:09
>
> seeesion ==== 2019-04-11T14:57:09

We have bolded the incorrect event.

```
self.sessionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 
TimeInterval(self.eventDuration), repeats: true, block: { (timer) in

print("seeesion ==== \(Formatter.preciseLocalTime.string(from:Date()))")

})
```

Comment: Well, no timer is precise enough, so depending on your device CPU load it may fire a bit later.

Comment: The timer is approximate, but 10 seconds seems extreme.  Are you doing any long running functions on the main thread?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746336/high-precision-timer-in-swift if you need a precise timer.

Comment: “App Nap” might be a reason – if the app is “inactive” then timers are coalesced aggressively.

Comment: @vacawama we are developing macOS application which required high precise time.there is no any function right.

Comment: Try it with `DispatchQue`.